How to handle dependent effect sizes in meta-analysis with a single control group?
I am conducting a meta-analysis and need advice on extracting effect sizes from studies where multiple treatment groups are compared to a single control group. Specifically, I am dealing with standard mean differences (Hedge's g) for three different drug doses, but there is only one vehicle (control) group. I want to extract the effect sizes at the 30-minute mark post-administration.
Given that the three effect sizes are not independent (since they share the same control group), what would be the best strategy to follow in this situation? How can I accurately account for the dependence between these effect sizes in my meta-analysis?
Any guidance or references to relevant methods that can handle this issue effectively would be greatly appreciated.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The chapter by Gleser and Olkin (2009) in The handbook of research synthesis and meta-analysis describes how to compute the covariance between two standardized mean differences that share a common control group. This allows you to construct the variance-covariance matrix of the sampling errors, which is used for fitting an appropriate multivariate/multilevel model (e.g., adding random effects for studies and estimates within studies). R code corresponding to the chapter is given here:
https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:gleser2009

Thank you very much! Your response was really helpful :)
